# Amount Box Does Not Add Up When Using Chrome/FF Increment Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a totals fields which adds to 2 fields together on keyup (this works fine) but in FireFox/Chrome amount fields also display the amount up/down arrows.

How can I capture this so that it adds up if the user uses these? remember IE does not support this though.

```
function Totals() {
    var Amount = parseFloat($("#OneOffPayment_Textbox").val());
    var BacsFee = parseFloat($("#BacsFee_Textbox").val());
    var ChapsFee = parseFloat($("#ChapsFee_Textbox").val());
    var e = document.getElementById("PaymentMethod_DropDownList");

    if ($('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val() == '' || $('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val() < '0.00' || $('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val() == '0.00' && e.options[e.selectedIndex].text == 'BACS') {
        $('#OneOffPayment_Submit').attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else if ($('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val() == '' || $('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val() < '0.00' || $('#OneOffPayment_Textbox').val() == '0.00' && e.options[e.selectedIndex].text == 'CHAPS') {
        $('#OneOffPayment_Submit').attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].text == 'CHAPS') {
        $("#TotalAmount_Textbox").val((Amount + ChapsFee).toFixed(2));
        $('#OneOffPayment_Submit').attr("disabled", false);
    } 
    else {
        $("#TotalAmount_Textbox").val((Amount + BacsFee).toFixed(2));
        $('#OneOffPayment_Submit').attr("disabled", false);
    }
 }

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#OneOffPayment_Textbox").keyup(function() {          
        Totals();
    });
});
```

All the above works when a user manually types in the field as i said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook your event up to both the `keyup` and `change` events:

```
$("#OneOffPayment_Textbox").on('keyup change', function() {          
    Totals();
});
```